# Load pages using AJAX (JavaScript) & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm Ryan and I'm stuck... I want to build a administration page where you can toggle between pages without loading synchronous (using AJAX)... But that's not the problem, the problem is that I'm using JavaScript (jQuery) to resize elements, then I used JavaScript (AJAX) to load a php-script asynchronous... The php-script has also different elements where JavaScript (mostly jQuery) is implemented... So JavaScript works, then php works, but after JavaScript refuses to work! How can I mak this correct?

This is how it's looking like:
[image: layout of the admin page]

index.php:

```
<?php
    session_start ();
    require ('php/content.php');

    if (!isset($_SESSION["admin"])) {
        $_SESSION["admin"] = false;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Administratiepagina van Polen</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <?php if ($_SESSION["admin"]) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/page.js"></script>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="stylesheets/admin_style.js"></script>';
        } else {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="stylesheets/login_style.js"></script>';
        }    ?>
    </head>
    <body id="body" >
        <?php load_page (); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

php -> content.php:

```
<?php

    function load_page () {

        if ($_SESSION["admin"] !== true) {
            login_content ();
        } else {
            page_content ();
        }

    }

    function login_content () {

        if ( isset($_SESSION["lock"]) && ($_SESSION["lock"] - time()) > 0 ) {

            // still in progress...
            echo "<div class='login-box'>";
            echo "<div class='title'><h1>administratie</h1></div>";
            echo "<h1>U moet nog " . ($_SESSION["lock"] - time()) . " seconden wachten!";
            echo "</div>";

        } else {

            // require login.php
            require_once ('login.php');

            // standaard login form
            echo "<form action='' method='POST' class='login-box' autocomplete='off' autocorrect='off' autocapitalize='off' >";
            echo "<div class='title'><h1>administratie</h1></div>";
            echo "<div class='login' >";
            echo "<input name='username' class='username' type='text' placeholder='gebruikersnaam'/> ";
            echo "<input name='password' class='password' type='password' placeholder='wachtwoord'/> ";

            if (isset($_SESSION["error"])) {
                echo "<p class='error' >* " . $_SESSION["error"] .  "</p>";
            }

            echo "<input name='login' class='login-button' type='submit' value='Inloggen'/> ";

            echo "</div>";
            echo "</form>";

        }

    }

    function page_content () {

        /*** variables ***/
        if (!isset($_POST["tab"]))
            $_POST["tab"] = "Startpagina";

        /*** header ***/
        echo "<div class='header' >";

        /*** require logout.php ***/
        require_once ('logout.php');

        echo "<form action='' method='POST' class='logout' >";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Log uit' name='logout' >";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "</div>";

        /*** main div ***/
        echo "<div class='total-frame' >";

        /*** main menu ***/
        echo "<form action='' method='POST' class='list-menu' >";

        echo "<input type='submit' value='Startpagina' name='tab' />";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Agenda' name='tab' />";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Klanten' name='tab' />";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Personeel' name='tab' />";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Website' name='tab' />";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Documenten' name='tab' />";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Instellingen' name='tab' />";

        echo "</form>";

        /*** main content ***/
        echo "<div class='mainframe'>";
        echo    "<div class='frame-header'>";
        echo        "<h1>" . $_POST["tab"] . "</h1>";
        echo        "<nav>";
        echo            "<ul>";

        echo                "<li><input type='submit' value='' name='tab' /></li>";

        echo            "</ul>";
        echo        "</nav>";
        echo    "</div>";
        echo    "<div class='frame-content'>";

        echo    "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

    }

?>
```

php -> login.php:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
        login ();
    }

    function login () {

        // ontvangen variabelen
        $_username  = $_POST["username"];
        $_password  = $_POST["password"];

        // benodigde variabelen van de database
        $_server    = "something.host.com";
        $_user      = "user";
        $_pass      = "pass";
        $_database  = "database";

        // connectie maken met de database
        $_connection = mysqli_connect($_server, $_user, $_pass, $_database);

        // de input velden escapen
        $_username  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_connection, $_username);
        $_password  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_connection, $_password);

        unset ($_SESSION["error"]);

        // controle: waardes zijn niet gelijk aan NULL
        if (!isset($_username) || !isset($_password)) {
            Error ("Alle velden zijn verplicht!");
        } else {

            // controle: voldoen de ingevulde waarden aan de eisen
            $_pattern = "/^[A-Za-z0-9!@#%&*]{6,20}$/";

            if (!preg_match($_pattern, $_username) || !preg_match($_pattern, $_password)) {
                Error ("Vul re&#235;le waarden in!");
            } else {

                // controle: verbinding met de database
                if (!$_connection) {
                    Error ("Geen verbinding!");
                } else {

                    // verbinden met de database
                    $_sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_username' AND password = MD5('$_password') AND admin = 1 ";
                    $_result = mysqli_query($_connection, $_sql);

                    // controle: feedback is van de database
                    if (!$_result) {
                        Error ("Geen feedback van de database!");
                    } else {

                        // controle: bestaan van het account
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($_result) != 1) {
                            Error ("Dit account bestaat niet!");
                        } else {
                            $_SESSION["admin"] = true;
                            header('location: http://admin.vanpolencv.nl');
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function Error ($_message) {
        $_SESSION["error"] = $_message;
        return;
    }

?>
```

php -> logout.php:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["logout"])) {
        logout ();
    }

    function logout () {

        // benodigde variabelen van de database
        $_server    = "something.host.com";
        $_user      = "user";
        $_pass      = "pass";
        $_database  = "database";

        // connectie maken met de database
        $_connection = mysqli_connect($_server, $_user, $_pass, $_database);

        unset ($_SESSION["error"]);

        session_destroy ();
        header('location: http://admin.vanpolencv.nl');

        return;

    }

    function Error ($_message) {
        $_SESSION["error"] = $_message;
        return;
    }

?>
```

php -> page.php:

```
<?php

    if (!isset($_REQUEST["p"])) {
        error ();
    } else {
        load_content ($_REQUEST["p"]);
    }


    function load_content ($_name) {

        switch ($_name) {

            case "home":

                echo "";
                echo "";
                echo "";
                echo "";

                break;

            case "agenda":

                echo "";
                echo "";
                echo "";
                echo "";

                break;

            case "klanten":

                echo "";
                echo "";
                echo "";
                echo "";

                break;

            case "personeel":

                echo "<h1>HALLO</h1>";
                echo "";
                echo "";
                echo "";

                break;

            case "website":



                // benodigde variabelen van de database
                $_server    = "something.host.com";
                $_user      = "user";
                $_pass      = "pass";
                $_database  = "database";

                // connectie maken met de database
                $_connection = mysqli_connect($_server, $_user, $_pass, $_database);

                echo "<div class='web_builder'>";

                $_sql       = "SELECT titel, tekst FROM " . $_name . " ORDER BY ID ";
                $_result    = mysqli_query($_connection, $_sql);

                while ($_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($_result)) {

                    echo "<article class='web_builder_content' draggable='true'>";
                    echo "<input type='text' value='" . $_row['titel'] . "' />";
                    echo "<textarea>" . $_row['tekst'] . "</textarea>";
                    echo "</article>";

                }

                echo "</div>";

                break;

            case "documenten":

                echo "";
                echo "";
                echo "";
                echo "";

                break;

            case "instellingen":

                echo "";
                echo "";
                echo "";
                echo "";

                break;

            default:

                echo "<h1>Deze pagina kon niet gevonden worden</h1>";

        }

    }


    function error () {

    }


?>
```

JavaScript -> page.js:

```
function page (page_name) {

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("frame-content").innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }

    request.open("GET", "php/page.php?p=" + page_name, true);
    request.send();

}
```

stylesheets -> admin_style.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(body).css('background', 'white');
    $(".total-frame").css('height', ($(window).height() - $(".header").height() - 10)  + 'px');
    $(".mainframe").css('width', ($(window).width() - $(".list-menu").width() - 20 )  + 'px');
    $(".mainframe").css('height', ($(".total-frame").height() - 10 )  + 'px');
    $(".frame-content").css('height', ($(".total-frame").height() - $(".frame-header").height() - 20 )  + 'px');

});

$(window).resize(function () {

    $(".total-frame").css('height', ($(window).height() - $(".header").height() - 10)  + 'px');
    $(".mainframe").css('width', ($(window).width() - $(".list-menu").width() - 20 )  + 'px');
    $(".mainframe").css('height', ($(".total-frame").height() - 10 )  + 'px');
    $(".frame-content").css('height', ($(".total-frame").height() - $(".frame-header").height() - 20 )  + 'px');

});
```

It is a complete disaster! Please help me! Already, thank you all for your attention!

Comment: This is for too much code for an abstract problem. You need to isolate specific problems and provide relevant code that relates only to that problem. Nobody can help you otherwise

Comment: statements like `javascript refuses to work` are meaningless problem statements

Comment: What do you mean with something like that? can you explain something more, please?

Comment: The point is you need to explain to us what specific behaviors aren't acting the way you expect, and what errors are being thrown

Comment: I want JavaScript to load after the php is done, but how can I do that? Or is there a better way to make the website responsive?

Comment: call your javascript after you set the `innerHTML `

Comment: What's the best way to do that?

Comment: put the code there or wrap the code in a function and call that function. Next line after you set the innerHTML